# Play (Scala) - AuthenticatedBuilder ... defaultBodyParser ... Where to get?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to create an AuthenticatedBuilder object and I am struggling with how to supply the "defaultBodyParser" field.

```
object Authenticated extends AuthenticatedBuilder[User](
  _.headers.get("test").flatMap(auth)
)
```

Complains of: "Unspecified value parameter: defaultBodyParser: BodyParser[AnyContent]"

Obviously you need to provide this field, but it's unclear where to get it from.  I know Play has BodyParsers already (JSON, XML, etc.) so... How do I supply them here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was in the ScalaDocs themselves.  Don't use an Object, instead use a Class like this:

```
class UserAuthenticatedBuilder(parser: BodyParser[AnyContent])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends AuthenticatedBuilder[User]({ req:RequestHeader =>
    req.headers.get("mytoken").flatMap(authCheck)},
    parser
  ) {

  @Inject()
  def this(parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {
    this(parser: BodyParser[AnyContent])
  }
}
```

So as you can see the parser is injected into the class using Play's DI.